# Let $ G $ be a connected graph $ a \in E (G) $, they are equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Let $ G $ be a connected graph $ a \in E (G) $, they are equivalent:

a) $ a $ is a bridge of $ G $.

b) $ a $ does not belong to a cycle

c) There are $ u, \: v \in V (G) $ such that every $ uv- $path contains $ a $.

d) There is a $ \{U, \: V \} $ partition of $ V (G) $ such that every $ UV $-path contains $ a $.

Demonstration. We will show $ a) \Rightarrow b) \Rightarrow c) \Rightarrow d) \Rightarrow a) $.

$ a) \Rightarrow b) $: Suppose $ a $ is a $ G $ bridge and is on a $ G $ cycle. By eliminating $ a $, we know that there is a path between two vertices of $ a $. But this is contradicted by the definition of a bridge. Therefore, $ a $ is not in a cycle.

$ b) \Rightarrow c) $: Since $ a $ is not in a cycle, $ a $ is a bridge, so $ G - \{a \} $ is disconnected. Thus there exist $ u, \: v \in V (G) $ such that there is no $ uv- $path, since $ G $ is connected then every $ uv- $path contains $ a $.

$ c) \Rightarrow d) $: Suppose there exist $ u, \: v \in V (G) $ such that every $ uv- $path contains $ a $, then in $ G - \{a \} $ there is no $ uv- $path. Therefore $ G - \{a \} $ is not connected. Let $ G_1, \: \ldots, \: G_l $ be the connected components of $ G - \{a \} $, by choosing $ u $ and $ v $, they must belong to different components, without losing generality Suppose $ u \in V (G_1) $ and $ v \in V (G_2) $. Let's define $ U = V (G_1) $ and $ V = \cup_ {i = 2} ^ {l} V (G_i) $.

Assertion: $ \{U, \: V \} $ is a partition of $ V (G) $.

i) $ U \neq \emptyset $ then $ u \in U $.

ii) $ V \neq \emptyset $ since $ v \in V $.

iii) $ U \cap V = \emptyset $ by the definition of $ U $ and $ V $.

iv) $ U \cup V = V (G) $ by the definition of $ U $ and $ V $.

$ d) \Rightarrow a) $: Let $ u $ and $ v $ be the extremes of $ a $, with $ u \in U $ and $ v \in V $, thus $ u \neq v $, as by hypothesis every $ UV- $path contains $ a $ and $ a \notin E (G - \{a \}) $, then there is no $ uv- $path in $ G - \{a \} $, from where $ G - \{a \} $ is disconnected. Therefore, $ a $ is a bridge.

it's okay?

Comment: How do you conclude that since $a$ is not part of a cycle, $a$ is a bridge? You never showed that $b) \implies a)$.

Comment: You write that you will show a->d->c->b->a, but you actually do a->b->c->d->a (either way is fine, of course, but posts should be internally consistent).

Comment: Your proof of b -> c starts with "since $a$ is not in a cycle, $a$ is a bridge" which is exactly the content of b -> a, which you haven't yet proved. Maybe it would be best to let us know exactly what you are using as the definition of *bridge*.

Comment: What is $A(G)$?

Comment: The set of edges of G

Comment: Any thoughts on my 2nd comment, Kitty?

Comment: It's not polite to ask a question and then refuse to engage with those who try to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy with other tasks.

Comment: $ a) \Rightarrow b) $: Suppose edge $ a $ is a bridge, but it is in a cycle. Consider the endpoints $ x $ and $ y $ from $a $. Let's remove $ a $ from $ G $. Suppose $ x $ and $ y $ are disconnected, since $ a $ is a bridge. But, $ a $ is in a cycle, so $ x $ can be reached from $ y $ (and vice versa) by following the cycle in the opposite direction from $ a $; therefore, $ x $ and $ y $ do not disconnect when $ a $ is removed, a contradiction since $ a $ is a bridge. Therefore, $ a $ is not in a cycle.

Comment: $ b) \Rightarrow c) $: Let's consider again the edge $ a = xy $. Since $ a $ is not in a cycle, there must be no other path connecting $ x $ and $ y $, otherwise $ a $ would be in a cycle. In this case, removing $ a $ from $ G $ should disconnect $ x $ y $ y $ in $ G $; that is, $ G - \{a \} $ is disconnected and therefore there are $ u, \: v \in V (G) $ such that there is no $ uv- $path, as $ G $ is connected then all $ uv- $path contains $ a $.

Comment: It's okay, @GerryMyerson ?

Comment: Those two parts look fine. I haven't looked at the rest, since you still haven't told me what you are using as the definition of "bridge".

Comment: A bridge is an edge of a graph whose deletion increases the graph's number of connected components.